# Using the KKT conditions to maximize the likelihood of a multivariate Gaussian sample

Tags: statistics, convex-optimization

Suppose $X_1, \cdots, X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\Sigma \in S_n^+$. The likelihood of the sample is given by:
$$L(\mu, \Sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(2 \pi)^{-d/2}}{|\Sigma|^{1/2}} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(x_i - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x_i - \mu) \right\}.$$

I want to choose $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ which maximize $L$. I know that these are given by the sample mean and sample covariance, but I'm wondering if I can prove this using the KKT conditions? This is a constrained optimization problem since $\Sigma$ must be P.S.D. Do the KKT conditions apply here?

Comment: The KKT conditions are for constrained optimization problems.  The only constraint here is that $\Sigma \succeq 0$.  Do you know how to produce the Lagrangian dual or KKT conditions for a semidefiniteness constraint?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I do not. Can you recommend a reference for this?

Comment: The textbook by Boyd and Vandenberghe discusses this in chapter 5.

Comment: But $\Sigma$ being p.s.d is not a constraint, it is a property of a dispersion matrix.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Why is it not a constraint?

Comment: If you don’t include this constraint in the optimization, you might get a matrix that isn’t PSD.